# How to select one of two namespaces with the same name

Tags: c#

I've a solution with a project named **Shared** and another project named *Foo1.*

In *Foo1* I've created a folder also named **Shared** so I've two namespaces named Shared in the solution.

I've added a reference of the project *Shared* in the project *Foo1*

But now when I type **using** in a file in *Foo1* IntelliSense don't show the **Shared** namespaces.

How can I specify in a file that I want to use the Shared namespace from *Shared* project in *Foo1*?

Note: The file where I want to use the *Share* namespace is in the root of the project (I mean outside the **Shared** folder)

Comment: Folders do not actually correlate to namespaces.  Check the `namespace` declarations in your files.

Comment: Is it possible to just change the name of one? Do they both have to be shared?

Comment: Foo1 should have `Foo1.Shared` versus `Shared`. You shouldn't have any collisions unless you're `using Foo1;` (in which case `Shared.Blah` may be ambiguous). But in cases like those, you can alias them (e.g. `using FooShared = Foo.Shared;`)

Comment: @SLaks I followed your suggestion and it works now!

Answer (score 2):

Given the following solution structure:

Solution1

---Shared (project)

---Foo1 (project

--- ===Shared (namespace/directory)

My understanding is that you want to reference something in the Foo1.Shared namespace from within a file living in the root of Foo1, presumably in the Foo1 namespace.

If this is all correct, you could explicitly reference each of your two Shared namespaces using aliases, like this:

```
using SolutionWideShared = Shared;
using Foo1Shared = Foo1.Shared;
```

You can now reference any class in either namespace using the alias, like so:

```
var blah = new SolutionWideShared.SomeClassInTheSharedProject();
```

or

```
var bling = new Foo1Shared.SomeClassInFoo1ProjectInSharedNamespace();
```

This is just one solution, but I'm a fan of explicit code, and this will make for some very readable, non-confusing code.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you should rethink your naming, and try to be more descriptive.  What is "Shared"? How is it different from Foo.Shared? In production quality code, this would call for refactoring and renaming, IMO. If this is just a dummy play project that you are using to prove some point or play around with some code - then use aliases.

```
using FooShared = Foo.Shared;
```

So you will have `Shared` , which is your initial shared project, and `FooShared`.